# Which one is the Github organization for reactivex.io?

Tags: rxjs, reactivex, reactive-extensions-js

There are two different organizations linked to reactivex.io:

- https://github.com/ReactiveX
- https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions

I see that Java extensions exist only in ReactiveX.

But, Rx.NET or IxJx exist in both organizations. However the former is active in Reactive-Extensions and the latter more active in ReactiveX.

Why there are two different organizations?

Answer (score 1):

`ReactiveX` is the repo created for RXJS 5 which is a ground-up rewrite of RXJS for performance purposes.

You can find more details about the changes between the two versions [here](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/MIGRATION.md).  My guess is that `Rx.NET` isn't on `ReactiveX`  yet because they aren't on version 5 yet.  It also seems like the various  languages are pretty loosely coupled and don't necessarily work too closely together on things like this.

Some source issues discussing this:

- https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/issues/1029
- https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/Rx.NET/issues/307
- https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/issues/1979